# WordPress | WP_Query | Get latest port from category and sub-categories

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have write a theme for WordPress and I like to have the latest posts posted in category and it's sub-categories to be displayed on top of any other post.

An example. Lets say I have the following categories:

```
Cat 1
    Cat 1 - 1
    Cat 1 - 2
        Cat 1 - 2 - 1
```

And then I create the following posts :

```
Post #5   |   Cat 1 - 2       | Date 2013
Post #4   |   Cat 1 - 1       | Date 2012
Post #3   |   Cat 1 - 2       | Date 2011
Post #2   |   Cat 1           | Date 2010
Post #1   |   Cat 1 - 1 - 2   | Date 2009
```

In the front end, when I navigate to **Cat 1** I do not get as latest post the **Post #5** that belong to **Cat 1 - 2** where it is sub category of the **Cat 1**, But instead I am getting the **Post #2**.

Currently I am using this code :

```
$categoryID         =   get_query_var('cat');

$args   =   array(
    'post_type'         =>  'post',
    'posts_per_page'    =>  1,
    'category__in'      =>  array($categoryID),
    'post_status'       =>  'publish'
);

$eiPost =   new WP_Query($args);
```

The problem is that this code return the latest post only from the top level category and not from the sub categories. How can I modify this code, in order to retrieve the latest posts from all the sub-categories and the top category ?

Is there any solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'category__in'` only displays posts from that category, not children categories.

Try using `'cat' => $categoryID` insted. So your `$args` would be:

```
$args   =   array(
'post_type'         =>  'post',
'posts_per_page'    =>  1,
'cat'      =>  $categoryID,
'post_status'       =>  'publish'
);
```